# How to list and manipulate windows files using C only?

Tags: c, windows, winapi, file, rename

I am trying to build a program to rename a bunch of files to a specific format. Problem is, I can't figure out the best way to find, list or manipulate windows files using C (using Visual C++ 2010).

I was able to do it in C++ using FindFirstFile() but I am trying to restrict myself to C only so I'm looking for another solution, which will also be more compatible.

Thanks.

Comment: `FindFirstFile()` is a C function, not a C++-only function. But it's not standardized in C, and perhaps that's what you meant?

Comment: You can do anything with `system()`, that's in `stdlib.h`. But I'd hardly call that C only.

Comment: May be you can perform your Bulk-Renaming with the Windows PowerShell. The editor and scrpting capabilities aren't that bad. I wrote a Powershellscript to rename lots of files, some times ago.

Comment: There's a whole bunch of tools that can do the renaming. It's just that I'd rather do this myself to practice my C programming :)

Answer (score 2):

First, `FindFirstFile()` is not a C++ function; it is a Windows function, which on Windows is also available in C (but is not available at all on other OSes)

If you want a portable solution, you can use the glib library's [directory functions](http://library.gnome.org/devel/glib/stable/glib-File-Utilities.html#g-dir-open) to list directories in a portable manner. There are functions for globbing (ie, processing wildcards) in glib as well.

Comment: Why would you think he wants a portable solution? Why does portability get mentioned in so many C/C++ answers?

Comment: He said "in C only", which can, depending on what the OP intended, imply portability. That's why I provided two answers - either use `FindFirstFile()`, which is available on C in Windows only, or use glib, which is portable to other OSes. Of course, there's no truly pure-C directory listing functions, but glib is as close as you can get.